# android Facebook SDK cannot share image

Tags: android, image, facebook, share

I am developing an app that can share an image to Facebook. 
Only I can share image, other people cannot share. I have a FAB and calling this activity on its `onClick()` method. I really don't know what to do, my app is live but when I click on my app name over the shared photo I get

"Misconfigured App

Sorry, MyApp hasn't been approved for display in App Centre."

What is the reason that others cannot share images? I really need the answer. Thanks.

```
public class ShareActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private LoginManager manager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");

        //this loginManager helps you eliminate adding a LoginButton to your UI
        manager = LoginManager.getInstance();

        manager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this, permissionNeeds);

        manager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                sharePhotoToFacebook();
                Toast.makeText(ShareActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(ShareActivity.this, "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Toast.makeText(ShareActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}

private void sharePhotoToFacebook(){
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://burakakyalcin.site/image.png");
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

        SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                .setBitmap(image)
                .setCaption("Hello")
                .build();

        SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(photo)
                .build();

        ShareApi.share(content, null);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
}
```

}

Comment: The app attribution link has nothing whatsoever to do with whether other users can share using your app or not.

Comment: So what is the reason that others cannot share image?

Comment: Did the user grant publish_actions to your app? Did Facebook approve your use of publish_actions?